# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ a Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ a Euclidean  domain?

I am confused, as I know that  $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]= \mathbb{Z}[-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} i]$

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ is Euclidean, but it is **not** $\Bbb Z[-\frac12-\frac12i]$.

Comment: Please omit "Pliz help me" from all your future posts, as it only harms the quality of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Bbb Z[\omega]=\{a+b\omega\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\}\tag{1}$$ $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ ([Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer#Euclidean_domain)), where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, is an Euclidean domain since it has an Euclidean norm $N(a+b\omega)=a^2-ab+b^2$. Also, $\omega=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: thanks u @cansomeonehelmeout